# Best C++ data structure for fast iteration and fast insertion/removal time

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm currently using an `std::vector` to store a list of children nodes in some tree structure I need, which can grow up in the millions. This is great for fast iterations and very cache friendly. However, the removal time is O(n) and this is a problem for large data sets.

What would be the best structure, given that I need:

1. Fast iteration, so it needs to be cache friendly
2. Order of insertion is preserved
3. Fast insert/remove time, at least better than O(n)

Fast iteration is the most important one, those children list are iterated over and over. `std::list` is not suitable, because iterations are not cache friendly. Maintaining a separate `std::unordered_map` for node indexes did not scale well for my use cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to get 1 and 3 at the same time. Do you want fast insert/remove at the ends or anywhere in the container?

Comment: I don't think there's a perfect datastructure for this in the standard library.
You could write something like a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, where you split your list up into chunks.
If you maintain around `log(n)` chunks (split and merge chunks using some heuristic), you will have amortized `O(log(n))` insertion and deletion.

Comment: @ChrisB it will be `O(N / log N)` insertion and deletion because each chunk has `O(N / log N)` size. If you want to do something like that, then making `sqrt N`-sized chunks is asymptotically the best. Then, both deletion and insertion by index is `O(N / sqrt N) == O(sqrt N)` to find the chunk (and index within it, so we can't just binary-search the chunk) plus `O(sqrt N)` for an operation within a chunk. This approach is basically an instance of sqrt-decomposition (at least in the way asymptotics get calculated, i.e. `O(N / M + M)` with M chosen to minimize it).

Comment: radix tree maybe, but it runs to problem of being cache unfriendly-ness. Tbh when assymptotically go close to these whishes, I take deque

Comment: @YurkoFlisk you're right, thanks for the correction. I meant sqrt, but wrote log.

Comment: An n-ary tree node can have four pointers:  `parent`, `child`, `nextSibling`, and `previousSibling`.  This makes the parent/child relationship a doubly-linked list and the list of children also a doubly-linked list.  This makes both insertion and deletion O(1) if you know the node you are removing.

Answer (score 3):

If it's suitable in other respects, I'd keep the vector, and add a small vector of indexes of items that have been deleted.

Keep the vector of deleted items sorted, so lookups in it can be fast--as you're traversing your main vector, keep track of the current position in the index of deleted items, so you do one comparison of the current index to the next deleted index. When you get a match, you skip that item in the main vector, and increment your current position in the deleted vector.

Limit the size of the vector of deleted items to no more than log(N). When it hits log(N), go through the main vector, and do all those log(N) deletions in one pass.

This should give (all amortized):

- O(N) insertion
- O(N / log N) deletion
- Almost no effect on iteration (one extra comparison and possibly increment)

Comment: How does this give O(1) insertion?

Comment: It isn't O(log N) deletion, it's amortized O(N / log N)

Comment: @ChrisB: what I gave were the numbers for one insertion/deletion, but yeah, probably not the best way to look at things.

Comment: If you chose √N, you'd get O(√N) on deletion, and also √N is much easier to compute than log N.

Comment: @PasserBy: Yeah, pretty much up to you to choose what you want. For something like this, we care little enough about accuracy, that we can compute log or square root about the same way (by find the most significant bit that's set). The position of that bit gives you an approximation of the base 2 log, and taking that bit and shifting it right one bit gives a first order approximation of the square root (e.g., a good starting point for Newton-Raphson).

Answer (score 0):

It os possible to implement node-based structures as vectors with node pointers replaced by vector indices. To keep the structures simple, you need to mark the deleted nodes with actually removing them from the vector. One approach would be - as mentioned in other answers - to keep a separate recordof deleted nodes (indices). For that I would use a `std::vector<bool>` to keep one single bit per entry in the main vector. Another option would be to store a validity bit in every node (e.g. `std::vector<std::optional<node>>> data;`), and store the number of deleted items. If the ratio between the size of main vector and deleted elements hits a certain threshold, a - possibly expensive - garbage collection routine should rearrange the vector and update the indices. Without further details, I guess there's no better possible recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, it always depends on the application where the advantages and disadvantages of a data structure lie.
I have had good experiences using the std::map type in large indexes (especialy with nodes). Here you could simply number the access key to create vector-like behavior (depending on the use). In any case, searching, inserting and deleting actions by haveing a lot of entries in the index is slightly faster than with std::vector.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question., but could make a decent comment Unfortunately because the Internet is a wretched hive of scum and villainy, commenting requires that you've built up a bit of goodwill with the server and community and demonstrated that you're probably not a spambot.

Comment: `std::map` is a node-based structure; not very cache freindly. It cannot be the answer to the problem at hand.

Comment: You are right.   ...The best thing is to do benchmarking with different types in the actual cenario/application. The only way to get the truth.